# Use string to access variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, variables

If I have:

```
name.sub = function() {
    var sub = {};
    var placeholder = "test"
    var test = function() {
        return 42;
    };

    // Desired code would be here

    return sub;
};
```

I want to use a `placeholder` to access the variable so that I get `42`.

Something like 
`window["name"]["sub"][placeholder]` is seemingly looking for name.sub.test.

The only answers I found were if it was a global variable.
Using eval would work, but I've heard it should be avoided where possible.

```
placeholder = "test"; 
console.log(eval(placeholder + '()'))
// Would return 42
```

My actual end goal is to have an associative array where:

```
console.log(array[placeholder]);
// Would return 42
```

Any help would be appreciated.

---

This is what I ended up using for anyone interested:

```
name.sub= function() {
    var sub = {};
    var placeholder = "test"
    var test = function() {
        return 42;

    var newObj = {};
    newObj["test"] = function() {test()}

    console.log(newObj[placeholder]())
    // Should return 42
    };
```

Comment: Did you try `window["name"]["sub"][window["name"]["sub"]["placeholder"]]()` ?

Comment: I don't quite understand the purpose of this. You can't have access to a "placeholder" that is local to a function outside of the function. You would have to define placeholder outside of the function or add placeholder as a property of the returned object.

Comment: Sorry; I probably did a poor job making my problem abstract whilst maintaining context.
There would be a `name.sub.input(variable)` where `input` would convert `variable` to a string (e.g. `"test"`). I want to find out what the variable `test` is equal to. 
Hope that cleared it up a bit. Though I think it'll be rabbit hole of why I want to do _that_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access local variables inside a function the same way you can access properties of `window` in global scope.

[kangax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/130652/kangax) wrote an interesting article about [Understanding delete [in JavaScript]](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/), which includes an explanation of what **Activation objects** are - which I think is what you're looking for.
I suggest you read the entire article, but long story short:

Inside functions, declared variables (and functions) are added as properties to the activation object of the current scope, as they get added to `window` in the global scope.
But unlike `window`:

> Note that Activation object is an internal mechanism and is never really accessible by program code.

Conclusion: What you're asking is not (currently) possible.

Your options are limited to:

1. Using an intermediate object:

   ```
   name.sub = function() {
       var sub = {};
       var placeholder = "test";
       var array = {};
       array.test = function() {
           return 42;
       };
       console.log(array[placeholder]());
       return sub;
   };
   ```
2. Using eval, exactly like you suggested:

   ```
   name.sub = function() {
       var sub = {};
       var placeholder = "test";
       var test = function() {
           return 42;
       };
       console.log(eval(placeholder + '()'));
       return sub;
   };
   ```
3. Using `window`, by removing `var` from `test`'s declaration:

   ```
   name.sub = function() {
       var sub = {};
       var placeholder = "test";
       test = function() {
           return 42;
       };
       console.log(window[placeholder]());
       return sub;
   };
   ```

I suggest the first option for the sake of performance over `eval`, for compatibility over `window` (might collide with other code), and simply because of personal taste and what I consider good practice.

Comment: Can I ask a semi-followup question please, since perhaps I'm asking the wrong thing.

I'm trying to do a gui, where you click on an item, and that item would then run a function. So I have a property in the item that has the name of the function that should be run when clicked. 

So basically I want to make a onClick function in canvas if that makes sense. Is this implementation above still relevant?

Comment: Instead of assigning a property to that item, I'd just assign it the function itself - if it's a DOM element, via `addEventListener`, otherwise via property. But for details on your specific situation, I suggest asking a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access variables inside a function from outside said function.

Instead, you could do this:

```
name.sub = function(placeholder) {
  var functions = {
    "test": function() {
      return 42;
    },
  };
  return functions[placeholder]();
};

name.sub("test"); // 42
```

I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for but hopefully it is. Explain more?

Comment: Thanks, but I was trying to keep everything within the function.
Basically to dynamically call a function based on the value of a string.

Answer (score 0):

By what i understand of your question,

its seem like you are looking for a key/value pair to a JavaScript object literal,

window.name is reserved btw: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name

```
var sub = {
    'test': function() {
        return 42;
    },
    'test2': 42;
}

sub['test']();
sub['test2'];
```

add by

```
Using dot notation:
sub.test3 = "value3";

Using square bracket notation:
sub["test4"] = "value4";
```

Maybe im thinking to simple , but seems like this is what you are looking for